# Why does my compiler insist on unused function definitions only for virtual?

Tags: c++, function, virtual, definition, declare

You can have however many functions you like declared in a class and the only warning I get is a little green squiggle when it's not used and not defined. I understand this.

What I don't understand is if I make the unused function virtual, then I have to define the function, even if I don't call it. However this is only if I instantiate the class. So in the following:

```
struct Animal
{
    void unusedFunc();          // <--- Regardless of whether class is instantiated, this does not need to be defined unless it is called
    virtual void unusedVirtualFunc(); // <--- Has to be defined whether or not it is called, but only if this class is instantiated.
};

int main()
{
    Animal dog1;          // <--- This line now means the virtual function has to be defined. Doesn't affect the non-virtual function at all.
}
```

As soon as I add the virtual keyword my class grows to 8 bytes (the vtable pointer). Travelling to wherever the vtable pointer points I imagine I'd arrive at the vtable which has the instructions needed to execute the function particular to the object, identified at runtime, but I can't see the need for this function definition to be in the vtable at all. Sorry if this is an obvious question.

Also, I'm on Visual Studio.

Edit: Here is some compilable code:

```
struct Animal
{
    void unusedFunc();
    virtual void unusedVirtualFunc();
};


int main()
{
    Animal dog1;
}
```

Comment: The linker is going to remind you that it needs the address of the function to fill in the v-table for the class.

Comment: It would help if you posted compilable code.  You're missing the return type for `unusedVirtualFunc` and the ending semicolon in the `Animal` struct.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks, I've fixed and added it.

Comment: [Problem doesn't happen for g++](http://ideone.com/7FsaJp)